# How to use the And function with the Not function in a VBA if statement

Tags: vba, if-statement

I'm very sorry if you can't understand this because i'm having a very hard time trying to explain what i'm trying to do but, basically i'm trying to make a cost sheet table that when you fill it out it will make a list based on what you mark off and if you don't pick some items then the other ones will pump up into that position.Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong here? I'm trying to get it to see if a cell is greater then 0 and if another cell is not equal to the "BBQ" then i want it to say "BBQ"

```
If Range("'Cost Sheet'!D87", "'Cost Sheet'!D88") > 0 And Not Range("B97") = "     •     BBQ" Then
    Range("B98") = "     •     BBQ"
```

Comment: In VB equal is `=` and not equal is `<>` but `NOT` operator exists, and do exactly what it say, it is the negation of the result. In this case it is equal to `<>`. This only regarding VB/VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but I have a few suggestions that may help you or someone else get a full answer. Also if you can provide some sample data and clarify if we are working on multiple sheets that would help.

First, I assume this code will look through a certain range reading different values? If so, I would convert the range of cells being looked up to Cells(). This will make it a lot easier to perform the task over a certain range:

```
Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cells()
```

Second, you may be better served with a loop for this. It would look something like a modified version of:

```
Lastrow = Sheets("Cost Sheet").Range("D" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row
For i = 1 to Lastrow
   If Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cells(i,4).value > 0 AND <> Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cells(i,4).value<> "BBQ" Then
      Cells().Value = "BBQ"
   End if
Next i
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately i'm very new to VBA as i just started yesterday, so i don't really understand the looping; however I will try it out and let you know how it goes!

Comment: “If Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cells(i,4).value > 0 AND <> "BBQ" Then ” wouldn’t work since you must specify both sides of each check: “If Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cells(i,4).value > 0 AND Sheets("Cost Sheet").Cells(i,4).value<> "BBQ" Then “

Comment: Yes you are 100% right. I even noted the error when I was reading, then repeated it. I've edited the code above.

Comment: @LiamRussell No worries, we were all new once and there's always something new to learn.